# Summing function in R

Tags: r, string, summary

I have data that looks like this:

```
Province     status
KZN           Open
KZN           Closed 
KZN           Open
KZN           Closed
OFS           Open
OFS           Closed 
OFS           Open
OFS           Closed
```

How do I calculate how many times the status "Open" and "Closed" appear per province. Basically I am looking to get a result that looks as follows:

```
Province  Status  Count
KZN       Closed  2
KZN       Open    2
OFS       Closed  2
OFS       Open    2
```

Answer (score 1):

`table` is enough

```
df = data.frame(Province = rep(c("KZN", "OFS"), each = 4L), status = rep(c("Open", "Closed"), 4L))
table(df) #See it's wide, and you asked for long

#        status
#Province Closed Open
#     KZN      2    2
#     OFS      2    2

as.data.frame(table(df)) #This turns it to long format

#       Province status    Freq
#1      KZN      Closed    2
#2      OFS      Closed    2
#3      KZN      Open      2
#4      OFS      Open      2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,.(Count = .N) , .(Province, status)]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    count(Province, status)
```